# How to upload an image in cypress?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cypress, jquery-file-upload

This is my code

I have install cypress-file-upload

- import below code in command.js file
  import 'cypress-file-upload';

```
describe('TEST', function(){

    it('File upload', function(){

        cy.visit('https://tinypng.com/')


    })

    it('File Upload using cypress-file-upload package', () => {
        const filepath = 'train.jpg'
        cy.get('.icon').attachFile(filepath)
        cy.wait(5000)
        
    })
})
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: No error comes.

Comment: try checking if the path to the image is correct.  I have had such problems when the path is incorrect from the fixtures folder.

Comment: no i have put image in fixtures root folder. I think path is alright.

Comment: If it is in the fixtures root folder you can check the config file if the fixtures path is correct - not changed for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `figure.icon` element on `tinypng.com` requires a file to be dragged onto it, but with cypress-file-upload the drag-and-drop option is not the default.

This will work,

```js
cy.get('.icon')
  .attachFile(filepath, { subjectType: 'drag-n-drop' })
```

If you prefer, there is an input on the page

```js
cy.get('input[type="file"]')
  .attachFile(filepath, { subjectType: 'input' })  // input is the default type, 
                                                   // so not strictly needed
```

Comment: What version of the plugin is there added drag-drop function?

Comment: The latest is 5.08, the one I'm using is 5.07.

Answer (score 1):

if you don't want to upload a real file use this, and if you want to make it drag and drop see comment above

```
cy.get('input[type="file"]').selectFile({
  contents: Cypress.Buffer.from('file contents'),
  fileName: 'avatar.gif',
  lastModified: Date.now(),
});
```